# How realistic is Detective Vic Manning's eye surgery recovery?

Tags: realism, stuber

In *Stuber*, Detective Vic Manning has Lasik surgery. Immediately after the surgery, everything is blurry. Over the next 12 or so hours, his vision slowly comes back into focus.

The one person I knew who had Lasik could see clearly right away (as I recall), but needed to sleep a long time immediately after the surgery.

**Question: How realistic is Vic's recovery process?**

Comment: I mean, you'd need some recovery time after having a laser in your eye. From those I've know, and recall, it usually involved keeping a patch over the eye for a number of hours. That was years ago, and things may be much more efficient now. I would guess the movie takes some liberties for the sake of time.

Answer (score 2):

When I had Lasik I wasn't allowed to drive until I had passed an eye test two to three days after my surgery.

Straight away after surgery my vision was poor (and uncomfortable). After an hour it was probably no worse than my uncorrected vision before surgery, probably actually better? But my uncorrected vision before surgery meant that anything further than 30cm / 1ft from my eyes was blurry.

12 hours from surgery to having good enough vision for basic functions sounds a bit slow. 12 hours to having good enough vision for driving sounds a bit fast.